# limit amout result from json array for chart.js

Tags: arrays, json, chart.js

How do I get it to limit the amount of existing onject in array JSON using Chart.js?
Suppose I have 120 onbject in a single array, then I want to only display only 10 data in Chart.js. My data exist in the firebase, I tried to use `limitToLast=10` , however, does not display any data, and this is my code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>

        <script src="JS/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
        <style>
        canvas{
            -moz-user-select: none;
            -webkit-user-select: none;
            -ms-user-select: none;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container" style="width: 90%;">
            <canvas id="canvas">
            </canvas>
        </div>
        <script>
            $.getJSON("https://skripsi-adeguntoro.firebaseio.com/sensor1.json", function (json) {
                console.log(json);
                var temp = json.map(function(item) {
                    return item.temp;
                });
                var time = json.map(function(item) {
                    return item.time;
                });
                var date = json.map(function(item) {
                    return item.date;
                });
                console.log(date);
                console.log(time);
                console.log(temp);
                var config = {
                    type: 'bar',
                    data: {
                        labels: time,
                        datasets: [{
                            label: "My First dataset",
                            backgroundColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                            borderColor: "rgba(220,200,230,1)",
                            data: temp,
                            fill: false,
                        }]
                    },
                    options: {
                        responsive: true,
                        title:{
                            display:true,
                            text:'Chart.js Line Chart'
                        },
                        tooltips: {
                            mode: 'index',
                            intersect: false,
                        },
                        hover: {
                            mode: 'nearest',
                            intersect: true
                        },
                        scales: {
                            xAxes: [{
                                display: true,
                                scaleLabel: {
                                    display: true,
                                    labelString: 'Time'
                                }
                            }],
                            yAxes: [{
                                display: true,
                                scaleLabel: {
                                    display: true,
                                    labelString: 'Temperature'
                                },
                                ticks: {
                                    beginAtZero: false,
                                    stepSize: 5
                                }
                            }]
                        }
                    }
                };
                window.onload = function() {
                    var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
                    window.myLine = new Chart(ctx, config);
                };
            });
        </script>
        
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.4.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

Thank for your help.

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: Sorry for that, i already edit the post @VaishalPatel